# How to programmatically add a UINavigationBar and a back button on it

Tags: iphone, uitextview, xcode4.3

I am newbie trying to make an app similar to Notes app of iPhone using `UITextView`.
I am getting the `textView` and lines and it is working fine.

My problem is that I want to add a `UINavigationBar` and back button on it.
And I want to add a `UIToolBar` at the bottom and 2 toolBarItems on it how to do this programmetically. Any help will be a great push up for me..

below is the code snippet.

**NoteView.h**

```
@interface NoteView : UITextView <UITextViewDelegate,UITabBarControllerDelegate>
{

}
```

**NoteView.m**

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

  if (self) {
      self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.6f green:0.6f blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f];
      self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MarkerFelt-Thin" size:20];
      self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.2f].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0f);

    CGContextBeginPath(context);

    NSUInteger numberOfLines = (self.contentSize.height + self.bounds.size.height) /   self.font.leading;

    CGFloat baselineOffset = 6.0f;
    for (int x = 0; x < numberOfLines; x++) {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.bounds.origin.x, self.font.leading*x + 0.5f + baselineOffset);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width, self.font.leading*x + 0.5f + baselineOffset);
    }

    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

**AddNotesViewController.h**

```
@interface AddNotesViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate,UITabBarDelegate>
{
    NoteView *note;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NoteView *note;

@end
```

**AddNotesViewController.m**

```
- (void)loadView 
{
    [super loadView];
    self.note = [[[NoteView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds] autorelease];
    [self.view addSubview:note];
    note.delegate = self;
    note.text=@"";
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [note setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView 
{
    CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
    frame.size.height -= KEYBOARD_HEIGHT;
    note.frame = frame;
}

-  (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView 
{
    note.frame = self.view.bounds;
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView 
shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range 
        replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Please tell me how and where to add navigation bar , back button and tool bar ,2 toolBarItems on it.Thanks in advance...

Comment: Duplicate.
[ButtonOnNav](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848055/add-button-to-navigationbar-programatically) & [NavBackButton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441699/uinavigationcontroller-back-button-custom-text) are already answered.
Go through [link](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) and [F&Q](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488710/how-to-set-a-picture-programmatically-in-a-navbar/13488781#13488781

Comment: are you using navigation controller or not

Comment: yes , am using navigation controller

Answer (score 3):

**Navigation Bar Image**

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[self navigationController] navigationBar];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TopBar.png"];
    [navBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

**Back Button**

```
-(void)getBackBtn
{
    UIButton *Btn =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [Btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,50.0f,30.0f)];
    [Btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"back.png"]]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[Btn setTitle:@"OK" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //Btn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:14];
    [Btn addTarget:self action:@selector(backBtnPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:Btn];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:addButton];
}
```

**BackButtonAction**

```
-(IBAction)backBtnPress:(id)sender
{
}
```

**View on NavigationBar**

For View on navigationBar you can follow my answer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890380/addimg-mutiple-button-on-navigation-bar-in-iphone-sdk/13890404#13890404)

Answer (score 0):

use this code....

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Back", @"")
                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                  target:self
                                  action:@selector(YourActionMethod:)];


self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = addButton;
```

Comment: I have to add that in AddNotesViewController.m of the  - (void)loadView right??

Comment: In the above snippet ,You observed that drawRect in noteView.M r8? That code is to draw the lines in textView , so this barButtonItems is not displaying...