# Adding a segmented control to the center of UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios6

I am trying to add a `UISegmentedControl` to the middle of a `UINavigationBar` of only one view (not the entire view controller). How can I go about doing this?

Other answers I read only allow an entire view controller to contain a `UINavigationItem` as the title. I need it to show only on one view.

Comment: follow my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890380/addimg-mutiple-button-on-navigation-bar-in-iphone-sdk/13890404#13890404

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565962/how-to-programmetically-add-navigation-bar-and-back-button-on-it/13619760#13619760

Comment: @Rajneesh071 Your answer from the other questions did not answer my question. Or are you suggesting to me to draw a view over the navigation bar?

Comment: yes i am suggesting you to add sub view over navigation

Comment: @Rajneesh071 Is that the only way?

Comment: title view....is the other way

Comment: @Rajneesh071 The app crashes when I do the following:

`NSArray *arrayOfItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C", nil];`
`UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:arrayOfItems];`
`self.navigationController.navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl;`

Comment: you can add sub view..and according to your query.."To the center of nav" you can add as subView, just chk ma answer

Comment: hey check my answer...its according to your question, mean adding in middle of navigationBar

Comment: I'm really grateful for your attempt to help me with this, but JayD's code explained it better for me. I only had to change 1 line of his code to make it work for my purpose.

Comment: ok dear..enjoy...but your question was related to adding in the middle..thats y i suggest you the answer...:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code will help you.

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Add",@"Delete",
                                             nil]];
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 30);
    segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    [segmentedControl setWidth:35.0 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [segmentedControl setWidth:45.0 forSegmentAtIndex:1];

    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    segmentedControl.momentary = YES;

    UIBarButtonItem *segmentBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];
    [segmentedControl release];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = segmentBarItem;
    [segmentBarItem release];
```

result of this code is

[image]

**Edit:**

Exact code that would work:

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
                                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Add",@"Delete",
                                             nil]];
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 30);
    segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    [segmentedControl setWidth:35.0 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [segmentedControl setWidth:45.0 forSegmentAtIndex:1];

    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    segmentedControl.momentary = YES;

    self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl;
```

Comment: I just used `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = segmentControl;` instead and it worked. Thanks! I'll edit in the code that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can add your UISegmentedControl as SubView to your navigationBar.

```
NSArray *arrayOfItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C", nil];
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:arrayOfItems];
segmentedControl.frame=CGRectMake(60, 0, 200, 44);
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:segmentedControl];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a UISegmentedControl centered on any view, and not only UINavigationView:

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedTab = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c", nil]];
segmentedTab.center = CGPointMake(segmentedView.frame.size.width / 2, segmentedView.frame.size.height / 2);
[self.segmentedView addSubview:segmentedTab];
```

Where segmentedView is a view that will contains our UISegmentedControl.