# Individual UINavigationBars for each view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a `navigation view controller` with `root view controller` where I set the look of the navigation bar. It looks like this:

```
UIImage *navBarImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"GreyUp.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBarImage
                                       forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This thing though, changes the `navBar` appearance for all the following view controllers, which I would not like. I would like one `navBar` for root view and another one - for a different view. How can this be achieved?

Comment: follow my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565962/how-to-programmetically-add-navigation-bar-and-back-button-on-it/13619760#13619760

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488710/how-to-set-a-picture-programmatically-in-a-navbar/13488781#13488781

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be achived use this in view will appear

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

// for cutom back button

```
UIButton*    btnBack= [Utils createButtonWithTarget:self selector:@selector(btnBackClicked) frame:CGRectMake(0,5, 100, 40) bgimageName:@"tab_back.png" tag:0];//My method use yours
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnBack];
      //use btnBack ref to change font title title color etc
```

My Utils class code to create button

```
+ (UIButton *)createButtonWithTarget:(id)target
                            selector:(SEL)selector
                               frame:(CGRect)frame
                         bgimageName:(NSString *)imageName
                                 tag:(NSInteger)aTag{
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
    button.frame = frame;
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];   
    [button addTarget:target action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    // in case the parent view draws with a custom color or gradient, use a transparent color
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
    button.tag = aTag;
    return [button autorelease];
}
```

Comment: need custom back button also?

Comment: Yeah, custom back button would be awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Appearance means It is applying into all your app navBar so you can add this in to your all view controller

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"GreyUp.png"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set your navigationBar for different view

```
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"login.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

get button on navigation bar you can follow my answer

[How to set a picture programmatically in a NavBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488710/how-to-set-a-picture-programmatically-in-a-navbar/13488781#13488781)

Answer (score 1):

In the `viewWillAppear` of rootViewController, customize your navigationBar.

In the `viewWillDisAppear` of rootViewController, do the changes which you want to display for rest of the navigation hierarchy..

Answer (score 0):

set a background color for your navigation bar or use Appearance method. where ever you want to change the image of navigation bar in viewWillAppear