# Not able to add action to back button of navigation controller iOS Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uibarbuttonitem

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIBarButtonItem *navigationBarbackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backToRootView:)];
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = navigationBarbackButton;
}


-(void)backToRootView:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Please describe the problem in more detail, just posting the code is insufficient

Comment: Use `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848055/add-button-to-navigationbar-programatically

Comment: Check this **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824186/trying-to-handle-back-navigation-button-action-in-ios/18824282#18824282**

Comment: try use self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = navigationBarbackButton;

Answer (score 0):

Here contradiction is that you are setting action event to `backBarButtonItem` and also set it to `hidden`. So it is not visible right now.

Remove below line from `viewDidAppear()` method:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Also it is good programming to call `super` class method for view life cycle methods.

So updated method will be:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    UIBarButtonItem *navigationBarbackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backToRootView:)];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = navigationBarbackButton;
}
```

**Edit:**

`backBarButtonItem` has default action to pop controller, you don't need to add an action event for that. I'm not sure about your concern to use back button but if you are trying customise left button item then must follow this code:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    UIBarButtonItem *navigationBarbackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backToRootView:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = navigationBarbackButton;
}


-(void)backToRootView:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: backBarButtonItem action can't be change. To use custom action or look must have to use leftBarButtonItem instead of backBatButtonItem

Comment: Yes. you are right that's why I haven't include action method. But if OP's concern is with just to change left bar button item then let me update my answer.